# Java Login session without use of scriplets:

Tags: jsp, session, servlets

I am new to Advance Java. I need your help.

I want to add a login session to my login page;

1. Without using scriplets.
2. With back button not going back to registration/login page

My code hits index.jsp first (Registration/login page). On logging in, Servlet is called and the home page (home.jsp) is displayed which has student data we can add, 
 update or delete.

I want my to be within home.jsp and not go back to registration/login page on pressing the browser "back button".

Attaching code for index.jsp below:(I have excluded css and bean class)

Guys please tell if more information is needed.
Thank you.

```
<%@ page import = "java.util.* "%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<style>
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: black;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Add padding to containers */
.container {
  padding: 16px;
  background-color: white;
}

/* Full-width input fields */
input[type=text], input[type=password] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 5px 0 22px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

input[type=text]:focus, input[type=password]:focus {
  background-color: #ddd;
  outline: none;
}

/* Overwrite default styles of hr */
hr {
  border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

/* Set a style for the submit button */
.registerbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.registerbtn:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

/* Add a blue text color to links */
a {
  color: dodgerblue;
}

/* Set a grey background color and center the text of the "sign in" section */
.signin {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Set a style for all buttons */
button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
}

button:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

/* Extra styles for the cancel button */
.cancelbtn {
  width: auto;
  padding: 10px 18px;
  background-color: #f44336;
}

/* Center the image and position the close button */
.imgcontainer {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 24px 0 12px 0;
  position: relative;
}

img.avatar {
  width: 40%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

span.psw {
  float: right;
  padding-top: 16px;
}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
  padding-top: 60px;
}

/* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 5% auto 15% auto; /* 5% from the top, 15% from the bottom and centered */
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
}

/* The Close Button (x) */
.close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 25px;
  top: 0;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Add Zoom Animation */
.animate {
  -webkit-animation: animatezoom 0.6s;
  animation: animatezoom 0.6s
}

@-webkit-keyframes animatezoom {
  from {-webkit-transform: scale(0)} 
  to {-webkit-transform: scale(1)}
}

@keyframes animatezoom {
  from {transform: scale(0)} 
  to {transform: scale(1)}
}

/* Change styles for span and cancel button on extra small screens */
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  span.psw {
     display: block;
     float: none;
  }
  .cancelbtn {
     width: 100%;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="MySrvletClass">
      <div class="container">
         <input type="hidden" name="add_me" value="REGISTER" />
        <p style="color: #cccccc "><strong><center>Welcome to University </center></strong>
        </p>
        <h1>Register</h1>
        <p>Please fill in this form to create an account.</p>
        <hr>
        <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required>
        <label for="mobile"><b>Mobile</b></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Mobile No" name="mobile_Number" required>
        <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>
        <label for="psw-repeat"><b>Repeat Password</b></label>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Repeat Password" name="psw-repeat" required>
        <hr>    
        <p>By creating an account you agree to our <a href="#">Terms & Privacy</a>.</p>
        <button type="submit" onclick= "${templink}" class="registerbtn">Register</button>
      </div>
      <div class="container signin">
        <p>Already have an account? <button onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" style="width:auto;">Login</button>
      </div>
    </form>
    <div id="id01" class="modal">
      <form class="modal-content animate" action="MySrvletClass">
      <input type="hidden" name="add_me" value="LOGIN" />
        <div class="imgcontainer">
          <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
          <label for="uname"><b>Username</b></label>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required>
          <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
          <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>
          <button type="submit" onclick="getComment()">Login</button>
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> Remember me
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">
          <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
          <span class="psw">Forgot <a href="#">password?</a></span>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('id01');
// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
</body>
```